# org.hibernate.id.IdentifierGenerationException: attempted to assign id from null one-to-one property (with session.merge)

Tags: java, hibernate, one-to-one

I have a problem.
I get error in my app: **org.hibernate.id.IdentifierGenerationException: attempted to assign id from null one-to-one property**

*My pojos 
User:*

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "user")
@Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.READ_WRITE)
public class User implements Serializable {
private static final long serialVersionUID = -5415891222321582213L;

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
@Column(name = "userId", length = 100)
private int userId;
...
@OneToOne(mappedBy = "user", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
private UserDetail userDetail;
```

*UserDetail:*

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "userdetail")
@Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.READ_WRITE)
public class UserDetail implements Serializable {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 2155190440305692224L;

@Id
@GenericGenerator(
    name = "gen",
    strategy = "foreign",
    parameters = @Parameter(name = "property", value = "user")
    )
@GeneratedValue(generator = "gen")
@Column(name = "userId", length = 100)
private int userId;
...
@OneToOne
@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn
private User user;
```

*Table User:*

```
CREATE TABLE `user` (
    `userId` INT(100) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `name` VARCHAR(255) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `surname` VARCHAR(255) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `email` VARCHAR(255) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `password` VARCHAR(255) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`userId`)
)
COLLATE='utf8_general_ci'
ENGINE=InnoDB
;
```

*Table UserDetail*

```
CREATE TABLE `userdetail` (
    `userId` INT(100) NOT NULL,
    `country` VARCHAR(255) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `city` VARCHAR(255) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `address` VARCHAR(255) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`userId`)
)
COLLATE='utf8_general_ci'
ENGINE=InnoDB
;
```

*DAO Layer:*

```
private Session session = HibernateUtil.getHibernateUtil().getSession();
@Override
public void create(T t) throws DaoException {
        Object object = session.merge(t);
        session.save(object);
        log.info("Update: " + t);
}
```

*Service Layer*

```
private Session session = HibernateUtil.getHibernateUtil().getSession();
private Transaction transaction = null;
private Dao<T> dao = new BaseDao<T>();
@Override
public void create(T t) throws DaoException {
    try {
        transaction = session.beginTransaction();
        dao.create(t);
        transaction.commit();
        log.info("Create: " + t);
    } catch (HibernateException e) {
        log.error("Error creating " + getPersistentClass() + " in Dao " + e);
        transaction.rollback();
        throw new DaoException(e);
    }
}
```

*Class with saving User*

```
User user = new User(name, surname, email, password);
UserDetail userDetail = new UserDetail(country, city, address);
user.setUserDetail(userDetail);
userDetail.setUser(user);
userService.create(user);
```

*HiberUtil*

```
public class HibernateUtil {
    private static Logger log = Logger.getLogger(HibernateUtil.class);
    private static HibernateUtil util = null;
    private static SessionFactory sessionFactory = null;
    private static final ThreadLocal<Session> sessions = new ThreadLocal<Session>();

    private HibernateUtil() {
        try {
        Configuration configuration = new Configuration().configure("hibernate.cfg.xml");
        log.info("Hibernate Configuration loaded");
        ServiceRegistry serviceRegistry = new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder().applySettings(configuration.getProperties()).build();
        log.info("Hibernate serviceRegistry created");
        sessionFactory = configuration.buildSessionFactory(serviceRegistry);
        } catch (Throwable e) {
            log.error("Initial SessionFactory creation failed. " + e);
            System.exit(0);
        }
    }

    public Session getSession () {
        Session session = sessions.get();
        if (session == null) {
            session = sessionFactory.openSession();
            sessions.set(session);
        } 
        return session;
    }

    public static synchronized HibernateUtil getHibernateUtil(){
        if (util == null){
            util = new HibernateUtil();
        }
        return util;
    }
}
```

*If i change in DAO layer:*

```
@Override
public void create(T t) throws DaoException {
        session.save(t);
        log.info("Create: " + t);
}
```

I get error: **org.hibernate.HibernateException: Illegal attempt to associate a collection with two open sessions**

So I have 4 questions:

1. If I understood correctly, when userdeteil save userId from User is null because UserId don't get icnrement Id from Table, it's true?
2. Needed session.merge here or not
3. If merge is needed, how correct org.hibernate.id.IdentifierGenerationException: attempted to assign id from null one-to-one property
4. If merge is no needed, how correct "org.hibernate.HibernateException: Illegal attempt to associate a collection with two open sessions"

Note: Delet with merge is good, create with merge other Entity (not User and not UserDeteil) is good.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my poroblem.
In my BaseDao and BaseService I removed:

```
private Session session = HibernateUtil.getHibernateUtil().getSession();
```

And I added in all methods in BaseDao and BaseService:

```
HibernateUtil.getHibernateUtil().getSession();
```

so I removed the two sessions
and my method, example create, became:

```
@Override
public void create(T t) throws DaoException {
        HibernateUtil.getHibernateUtil().getSession().save(t);
        log.info("Create: " + t);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To get it work, remove `Object object = session.merge(t);` from update method of your DAO class. Here is updated update method

```
@Override
public void update(T t) throws DaoException {
        session.saveOrUpdate(t);
        log.info("Update: " + t);
}
```

This will fix your `org.hibernate.id.IdentifierGenerationException` exception.

- For point 1: Your record was not saved, you were calling merge()
  method, then the object return by merge method is passed in
  save(here). **merger(): Copy the state of the given object onto the
  persistent object with the same identifier. In your case no
  persistent object.**
- For point 2: No merge method is not required here, use save or
  saveOrUpdate method with session
- For point 3: N/A

Here is a good example of [One-To-One association mapping](http://www.javamakeuse.com/2014/11/hibernate-4-one-to-one-mapping-example.html)

Comment: Thank you for answer, but if i remove merge(t) and call session.save(t), i get error: org.hibernate.HibernateException: Illegal attempt to associate a collection with two open sessions. Also with marge saving/deleting other entity normaly. If i remove merge, i get error: org.hibernate.HibernateException: Illegal attempt to associate a collection with two open sessions.

Comment: And in my post has mistake wich I edited. Instead of Update method I want write Create method.